# Inserting video into SVG animation purely in javascript

Tags: javascript, video, svg, raphael, vector-graphics

I want to insert a video clip within an animation I've created using SVG, Javascript using the raphael libraries.

I know you can insert images using

```
paper.image("play2.png", 400, 300, 80, 80);
```

and audio files using

```
var audio = new Audio('soundclip.mp3');
```

Is there a way to embed video?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure of a direct way (I guess I'm thinking foreignobject), but if you could put up an example clip and animation on a jsbin or fiddle, it may be possible. It may depend upon what the animation is, also things like browser support for workarounds, so a bit more info is needed.

Comment: Hi again Cylus -- I've been faced with a similar situation before.  I ended up just creating a div, positioning it over the top of the SVG element, and putting the video element in there.  Have you considered such an approach?

Comment: hadn't thought of that! I basically need the video to just play for a few seconds half way throughout the animation. How could I ensure the video element is responsive and doesn't take time to initialise and load? Would initialising it at the start of the animation and just playing it at the time required be sufficient? thanks

Comment: If I remember correctly positioning is a little uncomfortable, but it worked for me.  You should be able to add the preload="auto" attribute to the video element to get it to preload.  Some browsers won't obey it (Apple, I am looking at you) but most do.

Comment: You might use Kelley Reynold's Infobox to help you with the element positioning: https://github.com/kreynolds/RaphaelJS-Infobox or here: http://rubyscale.com/blog/2010/11/22/embedding-arbitrary-html-into-raphaeljs/ . I didn't try it though.